# Integrate Google Talk, voice & transalation in iOS app

Tags: ios, integration, google-talk

I want to integrate Google Talk, voice & transalation in my iOS app. I tried this [link](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)

I just show me my contact list. How can I start chatting or voice call from this ? 
If any one have idea or any other solution to integrate above services in my iOS app ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For chat, use XEP-0045

For voice, Google Talk uses [libjingle](https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/index) which is a C++ implementation of [XEP-0166](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html)/[XEP-0167](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0167.html)

For translation, you may need to find an implementation of [XEP-0171](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0171.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do I need to implement my own code for XEP-0171 & XEP-0166/XEP-0167 ?

Comment: You should be able to add libjingle as a dependency to your project - that should take care of the voice comms.  Not sure what you'd do for translation - Google charge $20/million characters - https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can I ask you for a favour ? Do u have any sample app for this implemented ? Would you mind sharing that app ? Because I don't know how to do this ?